# How can I check if the first word of a sentence is a proper noun?

Tags: python, nlp

I want to remove all the proper nouns from a large corpus. Due to the large volume, I take a shortcut and remove all words starting with capital letters. For the first word of each sentence, I also want to check if it is a proper noun. How can I do this without using a tagger. One option is to do a screening using a list of common proper nouns. Is there a better way and where can I get such a list?  Thanks.

I tried NLTK pos_tag and Standford NER. Without context, they do not work well.

```
 ner_tagger = StanfordNERTagger(model,jar)
 names = ner_tagger.tag(first_words)
 types = ["DATE", "LOCATION", "ORGANIZATION", "PERSON", "TIME"]

 for name, type in names:
     if type in types:
        print(name, type)
```

Below are some results.

```
  Abnormal ORGANIZATION
  Abnormally ORGANIZATION
  Abraham ORGANIZATION
  Absorption ORGANIZATION
  Abundant ORGANIZATION
  Abusive ORGANIZATION
  Academic ORGANIZATION
  Acadia ORGANIZATION
```

There are too many false positives since the first letter of a sentence is always capitalized. After I changed the words to all lower cases, NER even missed common entities such as America and American.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list from your corpus, of the words that are capitalized when they are not at the sentence start. A Bloom filter would be an efficient way to store the results, since you are willing to tolerate false positives.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just playing, you might dabble with Google's Natural Language API.  They provide an "Entity Analysis", where entities fall into two categories, "proper nouns" (specific people or places) HINT HINT :-) or "common nouns".

I'm only suggesting this as a starting point.  There's a threshold under which you can you can hit the API for free.  I think it's around 5,000 "entities" per month?

Disclaimer: I have no commercial affiliation with Google and haven't used the API myself.  I've worked on other language parsing projects and thought this sounded interesting.